Can the Kinzhal really fly 2,000km? Or can the ROCKS (at least its warhead)? Is there a way to tell fact from fiction for ALBM ranges?
Published ALBM (air launched ballistic missile) ranges are all over the place. For the Russian Kinzhal, wikipedia gives "an estimated range of 460–480 km". But another site (which was the first hit in Google for me) gives "between 1,500km and 2,000km".
Likewise for the Israeli ROCKS, FT gives 2,000km range. There is not much in the way published ranges elsewhere for this ALBM, but an Indian magazine (reporting on India's tests of that missile) says "well over 250 kilometres", which is not exactly a contradiction, but does look like underselling by a fair amount relative to the other claim.
Yet another page says "The range of ROCKS is less than 300 km". This might be for the export variant (to India), though.
Is there a way to tell fact from fiction for ALBM ranges? Of course, a lot depends on launching altitude, I suppose. Can one roughly estimate the max range, e.g. by assuming that a certain portion of the missile is fuel, and by knowing the external dimensions, which are perhaps less easy to fudge? ICBMs tend to be physically bigger than IRBMs and so forth for that reason, I assume.

I see that at least the burnout altitude seems somewhat easy to estimate https://www.armscontrol.ru/course/articles/primer.pdf (p. 4) based on the propellant and payload mass, assuming a specific propellant, but I suppose it's somewhat harder to guesstimate the thrust. Anyhow, even a range equation is given (eq. 13 on p. 7) based on the burnout altitude and velocity (ans some orientation). I guess the hardest to guesstimate among these is the thrust?

I see that ultimately that author assumes an exhaust velocity of 2.4 km/s for pretty much everything from Scuds to Minuteman.

@mins: none of that is what I'm asking here though.

@mins: fair enough, that bit probably does matter. FWTW, I see wikipedia gives "Mach 5.9" burn out velocity for the Iskander. I'm guessing the extra speed for the Kinzhal is mostly due to being launched at altitude, but who knows.

You can use an energy balance estimation to check if the claims match energy required and available. Energy available is calculated from the missile's propellant mass fraction and launch parameters.
A ballistic missile is assumed to get almost no lift and lose little to drag. Its most efficient flight path is a ballistic arc. The missile's delta-V ($\Delta V$) must satisfy two conditions:

$V = V_0 + \Delta V > V_\text{max}$
$V^2 / g > R$ where

$V_0$ is the launch platform's speed, $\Delta V$ is the missile's own energy, $g$ is acceleration due to gravity ($9.8\approx 10$ ) and $R$ is range in meters.
The two positive energy inputs come from air launch and propellant, calculated as $V_\text{aircraft} + I_\text{sp} g \ln(M_f/M_e)$ respectively, per the Tsiolkovsky equation -- where $I_\text{sp}$ is the specific impulse of the propellant, and $M_f$ and $M_e$ are the full and empty masses of the rockets. An empty Kinzhal probably weighs $\sim0.1 M_f+M_\text{guidance}+M_\text{warhead} \approx  0.1\times 4\,300+100+500 \approx 1030$ kg, giving it a $M_f/M_e \approx 4$. $I_\text{sp}$ for solid propellants is usually assumed at 240 seconds, but can be up to 295 seconds.
Solving for the Kinzhal:

$V_\text{max} = 10 \times 320 = 3,200$ m/s
$V^2 / 10 > 2\,000\,000$ , therefore $V > 4\,472$ m/s
Air launch at Mach 2, at 10 km: $V_0\approx 670$ m/s
Propellant impulse $= 2500 \ln(4) \approx 3\,460$ m/s
Total $V = 4\,130$ m/s

Conclusion: Using a conservative energy estimate, with the same weight, engine, and warhead weight as the Iskander, the highest claims of 2,000-3,000 km are not plausible. The missiles' best-case range can't be more than 1,700 km.
Furthermore, Mach 2 is pretty fast for a launch platform. A subsonic launch would further reduce range to $R=(280+3460)^2 \approx 1\,400$ km. An even faster launch would improve range, but solving for $R=2\,000$ km gives a $V_0$ of Mach 3, which might be possible for the MiG, but goes contrary to the stated 3,000 km with the Mach 2 Tu-22M3.
There are three possibilities:

The claimed range of 2,000 km originally included the combat radius of the launch platform. This is consistent with 3,000 km for the much longer-ranged Tu-22. But the missile itself only covers 1,000-1,700 km.
It's only loosely based on the Iskander, and uses a more modern propellant. It would take an Isp of 280 s to reach 2,000 km from Mach 2.
A combination of 1 and 2: the missile is slightly improved, but its range of 2,000 km is an impractical scenario for a top-speed MiG-31 zoom climb, and 1,000-1,500 km operationally.

The reports of Kinzhal's interception say it was nothing special, basically falling at about 1,240 m/s, which is consistent with an older boost-only rocket. Any upgrade would've likely bumped it to boost-sustain type, which don't lose so much speed near the end. Given that, I lean towards the first option, but the third is plausible as well.
But its range is almost certainly over 1,000 km, given how far they have struck, and also considering that air launch is a substantial boost to a ballistic missile's range.
As for the Rafael ROCKS, it's impossible to check without more specs. But overall, I'd expect option 1 for it as well. Israel's opponents have next to no air forces or defenses, their region of interest is geographically tight, and their military doctrine tends to favor payload to begin with. They don't have much of a use case for a 2,000 km missile.

I have a stone somewhere around with a range of 7.000 km (including the launch plattform range).

You say the stated range is not plausible, while calculating "only" 1700 km. However, the question stated an estimation of 460–480 km which is well under it, and the highest estimation was "between 1,500km and 2,000km", and 1700 is indeed between those numbers. So what exactly is not plausible?

@vsz 2,000 km or 3,000 as stated in wiki isn't plausible. But 1,500 is indeed possible.

Where is the $V_\text{max} = 10 \times 320 = 3,200$ m/s coming from?
And Mach 2 at 10 km is ~590 m/s

@ROIMaison I've added a little delta-V to compensate for the gravity drag, saved by the "free" 10 km. Vmax comes from Mach 10 times 320 (which is admittedly a semi-random number)
